# local image is not showing in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

first, understand my folder structure so I have written my all reactjs code in DevFolder and mdx files are in mdxContent folder

[image]

so the problem is I have used react component in MDX file and sending data through that component and processed data in DevFolder > reactComp.js and the data I'm passing through the component which are an array of object formate (see below )

```
---
title: 'India'
date:
description:
type: 'docs'
order: 4
category: 'help'
section: 'messaging faqs'
slug: /docs/help/messagingfaqs/content/india/
---

import { AccordionForFAQ } from 'smooth-doc/components'

# SMS FAQs

## India

<AccordionForFAQ
  data={[
    {
        question:`What is  registration?`,
        answer: `
        <p>Lol, Distributed Ledger Technology </p>
        `,
        imgRef: `'../../../mdxConent/imageFolder/awards.png`
    }
    ]}
/>
```

so the problem is images are not showing the image path is correct still not working.

here is my react code

```
    <div className="mdxAccordion">
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <div className="mdxAccordion-item" key={index}>
      <div
        className={`mdxAccordion-title ${
          activeIndex.includes(index) ? 'active' : ''
        }`}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick(index)}
      >
        <span style={{ maxWidth: '95%', wordBreak: 'break-word' }}>
          {item.question}
        </span>
        <span className="mdxAccordion-icon">
          {activeIndex.includes(index) ? '-' : '+'}
        </span>
      </div>

      <img src={item?.imgRef} alt="" />

      {/* <img src={require(item?.imgRef).default} alt="" /> */}
      {/* <img src={`${CONTENT_PATH}${item?.imgRef}`} alt="" /> */}
      {/* <div className="mdxAccordion-content">{item.description}</div> */}

      {activeIndex.includes(index) && (
        <div
          className="mdxAccordion-content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.answer }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

if I use this import statement then the image loads

> import img2 from '../../../mdxConent/imageFolder/awards.png'

tried with this too but it says Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ''../../../mdxConent/imageFolder/awards.png'

> `<img src={require(item?.imgRef)} alt="" />`